# Google Endpoints query returns only "etag" and "kind" instead of collection

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

On my Google Endpoints implementation, I have created a simple POJO like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Cartoon {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Long channelId;

    @Parent
    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    private Key<Channel> channelKey;

    @Index
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    private Cartoon() {}

    public Cartoon(final long id, final long channelId,
            final CartoonForm cartoonForm) {
        this.id = id;
        this.channelKey = Key.create(Channel.class, channelId);
        this.channelId = channelId;
        updataFromCartoonForm(CartoonForm);
    }

    public long getId() { return id; }

    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    public Key<Channel> getChannelKey() { return channelKey; }

    public long getChannelId() { return channelId; }

    public String getWebSafeKey() {
        return Key.create(channelKey, Cartoon.class, id).getString();
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void updateWithCartoonForm(CartoonForm CartoonForm) {
        name = CartoonForm.getName();
    }

    public String toString() { return new Gson().toJson(this); }
```

Two objects of Cartoon type were correctly created, however the query

```java
Key<Channel> channelKey = Key.create(channelId);
return ofy().load().type(Cartoon.class).ancestor(channelKey).list();
```

returns result 200 and the following JSON

```js
{
    "kind": "channel#resourcesItem",
    "etag": "\"HvVI34INX8_n_JiuB-aYaj2l4Mg/ulgdYniw-Q\""
}
```

Every time a create new Cartoon object, a web safe key of this object is add to a list of String inside the ancestor Channel object. So the strange fact is that if a create a `List<Key<Cartoon>>` from the `List<String>` and call

```java
return ofy().load().keys(cartoonKeys).values();
```

the method returns what would be the expected result:

```js
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "180001",
   "name": "Adventure Time",
   "webSafeKey": "abcdefghij",
   "kind": "channel#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "190001",
   "name": "The Amazing World of Gumball",
   "webSafeKey": "aghzfm5vcW",

   "kind": "channel#resourcesItem"
  }
 ],
 "kind": "channel#resources",
 "etag": "\"HvVI34INX8_n_JiuB-aYaj2l4Mg/ulgdYniw-Q\""
}
```

What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the Channel POJO also has an ancestor named `Satellite`, thus it is not possible recreate a `Key<Channel>` object from channel ID. Thus the query is working *perfectly*, i.e. it is finding no `Cartoon` objects because the informed ancestor key does not exist.

Looking at [com.googlecode.objectify.Key](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.java?r=67d1719fa001c314905b8fb326c1300bb3542efc) implementation on [Google Code repository](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), you notice that, if the ancestor has an ancestor too, you should recreate the key like this:

```
Key<Satellite> satelliteKey = Key.create(Satellite.class, satelliteId);
Key<Channel> channelKey = Key.create(satelliteKey, Channel.class, channelId);
```

But you have a valid `webSafeChannelKey` string object, you can just call:

```
Key<Channel> channelKey = Key.create(webSafeChannelKey);
```